# How to loop audio a certain number of times?

Tags: loops, embed

I am trying to repeat a sound 3 times. I tried the following:

```
<embed src="myaudio.mp3" width="100%" height="200" autostart="true" loop="3">
```

But the sound plays continuously, it does not stop after 3 times. How can I make this work?

Comment: What does *it is not working* mean?  Does it only play once?  Does it not play at all?

Comment: it is playing continuously but i want to set the loop to 3.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be consistent across browsers: http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/embeddedobjects/_EMBED_LOOP.html

Comment: I haven't found an answer yet, but search around for an html5 solution.

Answer (score 4):

The `embed` element doesn't actually have a `loop` attribute. You should instead use [the standard `audio` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio), which does have a boolean `loop` attribute.

Then, use JavaScript to listen for the [`ontimeupdate` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/timeupdate). When the `currentTime` equals 0.0, you know it has looped back and if you count the number of times this occurs, you can call `pause()` once it has looped the desired number of times.

```
<audio id="myaudio" src="myaudio.mp3" loop></audio>

<script>
var loopCount = 0;

document.getElementById('myaudio').addEventListener('timeupdate', function () {
    if (this.currentTime == 0)
        ++loopCount;
    if (loopCount == 3)
        this.pause();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this alternative setting the loops number:

```
<script> 
   var loops = 3;       
   var count = 0;
    myaudio.onended = function() {
        if(count <= loops){
          count++;
          this.play();
       }
    };
</script>
```